# How to solve multiple landing page redirect in Wordpress at once?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, gtmetrix

I have a Wordpress website and want to have in form of `https://website.com`. When I test it on GTmertix in form of `http://www.website.com`, I receive multiple landing page redirects like this:

> Avoid landing page redirects for the following chain of redirected URLs.
>   http://www.website.com/
>   http://website.com/
>   https://website.com/

I have set the base domain on `https://website.com` format in Wordpress, and also I have done many things on `.htaccess` file to redirect `http` to `https`, but could not solve this issue.
May you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Without the domain, it is difficult to diagnose (and even then it may be difficult without seeing your .htaccess). Something is obviously redirecting http://www.example.com to http://example.com rather than directly to HTTPS.

You could try looking further up the chain, such as at your domain registrar/DNS provider. If you are behind a proxy like Cloudflare, I'd also be curious if this happens when you add the instance's IP address in your hosts file and try connecting directly - that would at least determine if the issue exists on the host itself or further up the chain.